# Is it possible to remove and Combining partial duplicates

Tags: sql, duplicates

Ok I have a table that is bring back partial duplicates. what I mean is that in the result set all of the values are the same except for the dates. This doesn't make them real duplicates. So I can't just use a distinct and eliminate the value. My goal is to combine both dates and the totals in one line in the result set.

I have use the <> on the dates there were some other real duplicates that needed to be eliminated but Im at a stand still here. I have tried a cte but that just got me the same result set as the <>

```
ID  InputFood   InputDate      Total
335 Rice        2018-11-01     $5.00
443 Cookies     2018-05-03     $3.00
856 Tea         2018-02-10     $2.00
335 Rice        2018-12-01     $5.00 
443 Cookies     2018-01-03     $3.00
```

I'm trying to reach this output here.So I need to combine the dates.

```
ID  InputFood   InputDate      Total
335 Rice        2018-11-01     $10.00
443 Cookies     2018-05-03     $6.00
856 Tea         2018-02-10     $2.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a min(), sum() and group  by

```
  select ID, InputFood, min(InputDate ), sum(Total)
  from my_table 
  group by ID, InputFood
```

Comment: I will try this. One  more question is there something I can add to the where clause that could give me the same result?

Comment: looking to your data .. your result is not filtered  (so you don't need where).. is just a sum afor total  and min input date for each rows  group by id and input food

Comment: Yea this is a small piece of what im working on. The main thing im trying to get out of this there a ability to add these to dates together and sum all of the values for both dates. I believe the where clause is where i need to focus. Thanks though